# navigation bar css changes after a servlet is called

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, servlets

**Before:**
[image]

**After**
[image]

The first image is of the login page, but when I click login button the navigation bar becomes like the second picture, spaces appear between the blocks. This happens when a sevlet is called and has this code:

```
out.print("<p style='position:absolute;top:200px;left:300px;color:#CC0066;'>Sorry username or password error! </p>");
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
            rd.include(request, response);
```

The CSS code is:

```
#menuli{
display: inline;
float: left;
color: #CCCCCC;
}

#menuA,#menuAL {
display: block;
width: 180px;
padding: 10px;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: x-large;
font-variant: normal;
font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
margin: 10;
text-decoration: none;
opacity: 0.9;
border-spacing:0;

border-collapse:collapse;
text-align: center;
background-color: #000033;
/*font-weight: bold;
/*border-radius: 20px;*/
}
#menuA:hover, #menuAL:hover
{
/*color: #699;*/

background-color: #003;
/*text-shadow: 10px 0px 10px;   */
font-weight: bold;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50.00% 0.00%, 50.00% 100.00%, color-stop( 0% , rgba(65,62,110,1.00)),color-stop( 40.94% , rgba(7,5,53,1.00)),color-stop( 49.74% , rgba(9,8,56,1.00)),color-stop( 100% , rgba(12,11,60,1.00)),color-stop( 100% , rgba(54,56,116,1.00)));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg,rgba(65,62,110,1.00) 0%,rgba(7,5,53,1.00) 40.94%,rgba(9,8,56,1.00) 49.74%,rgba(12,11,60,1.00) 100%,rgba(54,56,116,1.00) 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(65,62,110,1.00) 0%,rgba(7,5,53,1.00) 40.94%,rgba(9,8,56,1.00) 49.74%,rgba(12,11,60,1.00) 100%,rgba(54,56,116,1.00) 100%);
}
#menu
{
position: absolute;
top: 126px;
left: 139px;
}
```

The JSP code is:

```
<div name="header" id="header">
    <img id="logo" style="position:absolute; left:145px; top:10px; "src="images/logo.jpg">
        <div id="menu" >
        <ul>
            <li id="menuli"><a id="menuA" href="index.jsp#header">Home</a></li>
            <li id="menuli"><a id="menuA" href="index.jsp#services">Services</a></li>
            <li id="menuli"><a class="prod" id="menuA" href="Display?course=6">Products</a>

            </li>
            <li id="menuli"><a id="menuA" href="index.jsp#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li id="menuli"><a id="menuA" href="index.jsp#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's happening with all the pages after any servlet includes it.

Please see the links for images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it fixed. I had `margin:10px` in the CSS part of the navigation bar. Removed it and the problems are all gone.

:)

Answer (score 1):

Printing the `html` content inside servlet is considered as bad practice . you can rather set the attribute in the request . so instead of this ,

```
out.print("<p style='position:absolute;top:200px;left:300px;color:#CC0066;'>Sorry username or password error! </p>");
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
            rd.include(request, response);
```

use,

```
request.setAttribute("message","Sorry username or password error!");
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
            rd.include(request, response);
```

And try to print the message in the jsp page,

simply using the scriptlet as ,

```
<p style='position:absolute;top:200px;left:300px;color:#CC0066;'><%=message></p>
```

or using EL

```
<p style='position:absolute;top:200px;left:300px;color:#CC0066;'>${message}</p>
```

using scriptlets are also considered to be bad practices since a decade . see this [How to avoid java codes inside jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Hope this helps !!

Comment: the change in CSS was due to this code? This would work?

Comment: the answer is in general . But you could eliminate the issue if you follow in above way . i guess `position:absolute` is the problem in your code . try changing it to relative

Comment: using what you said is working. But i will have to do it in the whole project. bdw what do you mean by position:absolute is the problem?? What should i replace it with?

Comment: well removing `position:absolute` does not changes anything. so i don't think the problem is there.

Comment: Have tried replacing it to `position:relative` . what do you say as working does that avoid your problem

Comment: Got it fixed. I had `margin:10px` in the CSS part of the navigation bar. Removed it and the problems are all gone.


But I wonder why the margin thing wasn't visible first (Before calling servlet).

Comment: Because you don't have any thing inside it . margin is for the elements inside the div and not for the div

Comment: But what i m asking is that whatever the margin was for, it should remain unchanged even after any servlet call, but it changed.

Comment: Because you were appending a new paragraph to the existing html through the response from servlet which caused distortion .